# Custom width editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

So, I'm *attempting* to code a custom jQuery width editor that uses an input text box, and changes the width of specific HTML elements based on the input received via the input text box. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/miskhanception/nrpo085q/) is what I have so far. (JSFiddle)

The HTML and CSS is relatively standard, nothing fancy. I don't think there are any errors there. It's the JS + jQuery I'm not quite understanding. Particularly, why it doesn't work. Here's my JS:

```
var widthValue = $('#widthInput').val();
var widthFunction = function() {
$('#widthChanger').click(function() {
    $('#changedWidth').animate({width: widthValue}, 5000);
});
};
widthFunction();
```

I grabbed the value of the input text box using .val() and stored it in widthValue, created a function that animated the div - that changes its width to the value of the input text box when the button is clicked over the course of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds), and then called the function.

When the code is ran, and the button is clicked, the div animates - but it animates to where it's almost completely gone. The same thing happens if you type in anything to the input text box.

Can anyone explain to me why my code doesn't work properly the way I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be grabbing the entered width when the button is clicked, not before. Since you grab the width before any value is entered, you're trying to animate the DIV to an empty string width.

So you should be doing this instead:

```
var widthFunction = function() {
    $('#widthChanger').click(function() {
        var widthValue = $('#widthInput').val();
        $('#changedWidth').animate({width: widthValue}, 5000);
    });
};
widthFunction();
```

I'd also recommend setting the click listener in a `$(document).ready` callback instead of calling the `widthFunction` (but maybe you just gave a simplified version of your code).